# Extend Angular2 Directive

Tags: javascript, angular, clipboard, extend

I am trying to extend the angular2-clipboard npm package. I need to get access to its `ngOnInit()` function and override it to suit a specific use case for copying.

I am new to angular2 and unsure how to do this, the way I've been trying it so far is linked in the plunker below. I am having difficulty since the package is exported as a module called ClipboardModule and I need the directive.

Here is the plugin github and plunker for reference:

1. Github: https://github.com/maxisam/angular2-clipboard

   - The file that shows the export is src/clipboard.module.ts
   - Their github also has a link to a plunker example of it working
2. My plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/sIxmFo/

Answer (score 0):

This is how one defines a service, not a directive.

```
@Injectable()
export default class CopyDirective extends ClipboardModule {
        public cm: any; // better way than any?

    constructor(cm: ClipboardModule) {
        super();
        this.cm = cm;
    }
}
```

A directive requires a `@Directive()` decorator instead of the `@Injectable()`

Inheritance with components, directives, and pipes isn't supported currently.

I also don't understand why you extend a module when you want to extend a directive. You need to extend the directive class directly.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11606

Some scenarios can work though. 
Usually you need to repeat all decorators in the subclass.

`@Component()`, `@Directive()`, `@Input()`, `@Output()`, `@ViewChild(ren)()`, `@ContentChild(ren)()`. ...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! The problem I was having with this package is that its exported as a module. Is there a way to reach through the ClipboardModule to access the directive? I didn't think I should try to do something like `import { ClipboardDirective } from "node/modules/etc" `

Comment: I see. I don't know about that. I'm not actively using Angular2 with TS (only Dart).

Comment: @caraec Try this `import { ClipboardDirective }  from "angular2-clipboard/src/clipboard.directive";`

Comment: @yurzui that seems to be working great! Thanks! I updated my code as well to use `@Directive` etc